# Workflow recording/storing tracker

Tags: document-management

I am a graphic designer in the Marketing Department. Looking for an app solution that I can store ALL information on each project (emails, mockups, scans, drafts etc.). Also must be able to store emails from MS Outlook pertaining to project (I must be able to drag/attached the complete email.

I want to stop storing paper printouts of everything.

Answer (score 0):

For the storing part I would recommend using a well structured directory tree that is identical across projects. This takes discipline to set-up and use, but really pays of later when you need to find a file, or show hand-over a project to someone else.

To keep it all accessible I would recommend [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) with the [uLister plugin](https://totalcmd.net/plugring/oilister.html) and the [voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) search application.

- **Total commander** is a highly customizable two pane [file manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager) and will allow you to create a [hotlist](https://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Directory_hotlist) of all your projects.
- **uLister** is a plugin for Total Commander and allows you to preview all kinds of files, including office documents, images, zip files, pdf's and outlook e-mails (.msg files). If uLister does not support a filetype, there are [many other preview plugins](https://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm#lister) that probably do.
- **Everything** is a file indexer that allows Total Commander to search files by (part of) their name very quickly.

It's not a 1 click solution, it will take you half a day to setup initially, it will take you several days to tweak and get used to, but after that you will have a highly streamlined file management system that will increase your productivity.